# Find A subspace with maximum dimension such that the quadratic form is non negative.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given a quadratic form $q(x,y,z)=-x^2+y^2-3z^2+4xy-2yz-4xz$ for all $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}$, find a subspace of $ \mathbb{R^3}  $ with maximum dimension such that the quadratic form is non negative.

$q$ can be represented by a sum of squares:

$ q(x,y,z)= -(x+2y-2z)^2 +5(y-z)^2 - (2z)^2 $

So I find that for $ W= Sp\{(2,1,0)\} $, $q$ is non-negative for all $w\in W$.

How can I show that there is no other subspace of $ \mathbb{R^3}$  with dimension  $2 $ such that $q$  is non-negative on the subspace?

Answer (score 0):

The number of positive coefficients when you represent a quadratic form as a sum of squares is equal to the maximum dimension of a subspace on which it is positive definite.

In this case, there is one positive coefficient, and so the largest subspace on which $q$ is positive definite is $1$.

Comment: How can I show this claim?